# Passing a bash variable to git formatter

Tags: bash

I want to pass an integer saved in a bash variable to `git show --format`, how can I do this?
When I pass the variable the git formatter treats it like a literal and doesn't retrieve its value, instead printing out the name of the variable.
I've written a script that does some processing but for brevity I will paste the relevant part of the script:

```
git show -s --format='%C(yellow)commit %H%C(reset) %C(magenta bold)(commit message lines: $lines)%C(reset)%n%B' $i
```

Currently, it outputs something like:

```
commit 6fc73ae81627edf220d3005eafbdd3d7f5f898d7 (commit message lines: $lines)
Fix foo

Fixing foo consisted of:
- Fixing bar
- Fixing baz
```

What I want it to output is instead:

```
commit 6fc73ae81627edf220d3005eafbdd3d7f5f898d7 (commit message lines: 5)
Fix foo

Fixing foo consisted of:
- Fixing bar
- Fixing baz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break out of the single quote, append your variable, then resume the single quote.  As long as there's no spaces in between, the shell will treat it as a single value (see [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting)):

```
--format='%C(yellow)commit %H%C(reset) %C(magenta bold)(commit message lines: '"$lines"')%C(reset)%n%B'
```

Comment: Thanks, works as expected.  
Thanks for the link, useful to know. I'll mark this answer as accepted as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular case it is safe to quote the format string with double quotes instead of single quotes:

```
git show -s --format="%C(yellow)commit %H%C(reset) %C(magenta bold)(commit message lines: $lines)%C(reset)%n%B" $i
```

Inside double quotes the shell performs variable expansion, inside single quotes it doesn't:

```
> echo "HOME=$HOME"
HOME=/home/leon
> echo 'HOME=$HOME'
HOME=$HOME
```

Comment: While this being a useful tip it doesn't provide a solution or suggestion to how I can resolve my question.

Comment: @PetrusK. Inside double quotes the shell performs variable expansion, inside single quotes it doesn't. See the example in the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using your solution in my script as it's less cluttery than using single quotes.

Comment: But you must be careful with using double quotes, to avoid unintended substitutions (when you have a literal `$` sign in your string).